# Finding an eigenvector with a zero column

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to find this eigenvector with a zero-column. If I have 3a + 0b = 0, then wouldn't that just give me ( 0 0 ) for the eigenvector? Can someone explain this concept?

[image: 1]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, the equation
$
3a+0b=0
$
implies $a=0$, but what does it say about $b$?

Comment: It doesn't say anything about b? Does that mean b can take on any value?

Comment: You never get a unique solution for the eigenvector as all scalar multiples of the eigenvector are also eigenvectors.  You can choose any non-zero value for $b.$  In which case, choose the one that is easiest to work with... usually $b = 1.$

Comment: Also, the equation $3a+0b=0$ relates to the eigenvalue $\lambda=0$, not the eigenvalue $\lambda=-2$.